# Pandas DataFrame conditional selection query?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets 
i).  SanFransisco Salary data 
ii). A fake Amazon order data

Now I have a doubt because in one data set my conditional selection logic works but in other I have to use another logic.

## 1. SAN FRANSICO EXAMPLE

```
import pandas as pd
sal=pd.read_csv('Salary.csv')
sal.info()
```

## DATA

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 148654 entries, 0 to 148653
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Id                  148654 non-null int64
EmployeeName        148654 non-null object
JobTitle            148654 non-null object
BasePay             148045 non-null float64
OvertimePay         148650 non-null float64
OtherPay            148650 non-null float64
Benefits            112491 non-null float64
TotalPay            148654 non-null float64
TotalPayBenefits    148654 non-null float64
Year                148654 non-null int64
Notes               0 non-null float64
Agency              148654 non-null object
Status              0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 14.7+ MB
```

## I am trying to solve this below question

QUESTION: How many Job Titles were represented by only one person in 2013? (e.g. Job Titles with only one occurence in 2013?)

```
len(sal[(sal['Year']==2013) & (sal['JobTitle'].value_counts()==1)])
```

This isnt working. It outputs 0 where it should output 202

```
sum(sal[sal['Year']==2013]['JobTitle'].value_counts()==1)
```

This is working. But it's not intuitive.

## 2. ECOMMERCE OR AMAZON EXAMPLE

```
import pandas as pd
ecom=pd.read_csv('EcommercePurchases.csv')
ecom.info()
```

## DATA

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
Data columns (total 14 columns):
Address             10000 non-null object
Lot                 10000 non-null object
AM or PM            10000 non-null object
Browser Info        10000 non-null object
Company             10000 non-null object
Credit Card         10000 non-null int64
CC Exp Date         10000 non-null object
CC Security Code    10000 non-null int64
CC Provider         10000 non-null object
Email               10000 non-null object
Job                 10000 non-null object
IP Address          10000 non-null object
Language            10000 non-null object
Purchase Price      10000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 1.1+ MB
```

## I tried to solve the below question using the failed logic above and it worked in this case

QUESTION: How many people have American Express as their Credit Card Provider and made a purchase above $95 ?

```
len(ecom[(ecom['CC Provider']=='American Express') & (ecom['Purchase Price'] >95)])
```

This gives perfect output here. I wonder why its not working in the above case.

## P.S. Complete newbie here, Just started 4-5 days back.

Comment: It seems your first `value_counts` is missing parenthesis

Comment: @Dav2357 Hey thanks for pointing that ,But with paren too its the same output along with this warning.
/Users/abhishekkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3140: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
/Users/abhishekkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for return Series with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
out = ((sal['Year']==2013) & (sal.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])['JobTitle'].transform('size')==1)).sum()

#count exclude NaN of JobTitle if exist
out = ((sal['Year']==2013) & (sal.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])['JobTitle'].transform('count')==1)).sum()
```

Alternative with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for exclude all dupes per columns, `~` invert booelan mask:

```
out = ((sal['Year']==2013) & ~(sal.duplicated(subset=['Year','JobTitle'], keep=False))).sum()
```

**Sample**:

```
sal = pd.DataFrame({'JobTitle':list('abccbbd'),
                   'Year':[2012] + [2013] * 6})
print (sal)
  JobTitle  Year
0        a  2012
1        b  2013
2        c  2013
3        c  2013
4        b  2013
5        b  2013
6        d  2013

print (sal.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])['JobTitle'].transform('size'))
0    1
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    1
Name: JobTitle, dtype: int64

out = ((sal['Year']==2013) & (sal.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])['JobTitle'].transform('size')==1)).sum()

print (out)
1
```

Comment: This looks way difficult the way you did it.
I am a newbie here. Thanks for the help though, I will try to digest this.

Btw can you help me in understanding why my logic is working on one sample data but not one other data?.

Comment: It working because it compare by scalar in second Data, in first need `transform` for create Series for compare. What mean it does not work with real data?

Comment: @Abhishek - But I have idea. First create new column like `sal['count'] = sal.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])['JobTitle'].transform('size')` and then compare like second data

Comment: @Abhishek - like `sal[(sal['Year']==2013) & (sal['count'] == 1)]`

Comment: sal['count'] = sal.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])['JobTitle'].transform('size') 
In this I do not understand the transform('size') function. Can you elaborate what it is doing? I will try to run it on my system to check it though.

Comment: @Abhishek - I think better it is explained [here](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html)